# How to write a recursive firestore query

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Here is my Guest schema:

```
{
 name: 'Frank',
 date: '2022-12-12',
 tags: ['REMOVED', 'COMPLETED'],
 state: 'BOOKING',
 ...
}
```

So to fetch guests,

```
query = query.where("date", "<=", startDate);
query = query.where("date", ">=", endDate);
query = query.where("state", "==", "BOOKING");
```

I need 50 guests for the first page and I need to filter the "REMOVED" bookings, but I'm not able to include the

```
query = query.where("tags", "not-in", ["REMOVED"]);
```

since inequality can't be with multiple attributes. So I do recursive call till I get 50 guests.

```
guests = snapshots.filter(snapshot => !snapshot.payload.doc.data().tags.includes("REMOVED"));

if(guests.length < 50) {
 // query again to get (50 - guests.length) guests.
}
```

But recursive calls is not working as expected. I know the schema(tags) is not great.

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this instead of recursive firestore query or whats the recommended way of recursive firestore query?

Comment: Why not use boolean properties for REMOVED and COMPLETED vs storing them as items in an array?

Comment: We have a few more tags. ALERTED, EXPIRED, FLAGED, etc. So using boolean won't work, right.